# Bokeh Crosshair X,Y axis values

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm very much enjoying the speed and features of [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html) currently utilizing 1.4.0 (not the 2.0) version. . but I cannot seem to get the X and Y values to appear on the axis.

Ideally anywhere I move the center of the crosshair to I want to see the X and Y value on the corresponding axis.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A hover tooltip for axes is still an [open feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3000) but looks likely to be completed as part of a Google Summer of Code project this year.

Comment: Thanks yes I did see this. I'll leave the question unanswered on the hope that one day this gets developed and we can see a proper full answer here.  It's both a mystery and a shame such a comprehensive charting package does not yet offer this very essential feature.

Comment: It's not a mystery. There is more work to do than people to do it, which is very often the case with OSS. We work as hard as we can, but there are very many competing priorities, and the only solution to get more Bokeh work done, faster, is for more people to decide to become involved contributors.

Comment: Indeed, I would love  to contribute but my coding skills are just not up to it, anything i tried would just be rejected as shit.

Comment: FWIW there are a range of issues from simple to complex, not all work involves any coding at all, and we always try to make time for mentoring.